# Finding the probability of occurrence of one event before an another

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

In a home work problem $E$ and $F$ are mutually exclusive events in the sample space of an experiment. The experiment is repeated until either event $E$ or event $F$ occurs. Show that the probability that event $E$ occurs before event $F$ is given by 
\begin{equation}
\frac{P(E)}{P(E) + P(F)}.
\end{equation}

I am assuming that this is a geometric processes with prob. that $E$ occurring is $p$ and $F$ occurring is $q$. Then 
\begin{equation}
P(E) = (1-(p + q))^{n-1}  p
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
P(F) = (1 - (p + q))^{N-1}q 
\end{equation}
where $n$ it the number of trials for event $E$ to occur and $N$ is number of trials for $F$ to occur.

Is this approach correct. I am not able to proceed from here. Can this processes be anything other than a geometric processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more easy to look at it as a conditional probability.

The main
question is: what is the probability that $E$ occurs under the condition
that one of the events occur?

Something like: $$P\left(E|E\cup F\right)=\frac{P\left(E\cap\left(E\cup F\right)\right)}{P\left(E\cup F\right)}=\frac{P\left(E\right)}{P\left(E\right)+P\left(F\right)}$$

Every time that none of the events occurs is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had originally considered this as a conditional probability problem, the mistake that I had done was computing P(E|F), so that left me with P(E). This makes more sense now!

Comment: You are very welcome.